# Minimizing Question

Tags: calculus, optimization

A closed box constructed from a tin sheet has a square base and a volume of $343 \text{in}^3$. Find the dimensions of the box, assuming the minimum amount of material was used in its construction. Show support for why your answer is a minimum.

I know that $V=a^3$ so that means a would equal the cube root of $343$.

I know that SA of a cube is $6a^2$

I was getting somewhere in thinking I needed to plug in A put then it asks for the dimensions and in class my teacher took the derivative of the equation we found. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

We explore how the total surface area depends on the side $x$ of the square base.

Let the height be $y$. Then $x^2y=343$, so $y=\frac{343}{x^2}$.

The surface area is $2x^2+4xy$ (top plus bottom is $2x^2$, the $4$ remaining sides $xy$ each).

We express the surface area as a function $S(x)$ of $x$. We get
$$S(x)=2x^2+4xy=2x^2+4x\cdot \frac{343}{x^2}=2x^2+\frac{4\cdot 343}{x}.$$
Minimize this. Make sure that you explain why the mechanical "differentiate and solve" procedure gives us the minimum.  You can do this by looking at the sign of the first derivative, or in other ways.

Comment: hmm okay so I should differentiate the 2x^2 + 1372/x^2?

Comment: No, you should differentiate $2x^2+\frac{4\cdot 343}{x}$. It is only an $x$ in the denominator, not a $x^2$

Comment: You will get $4x-(4\cdot 343)/x^2$. Set this equal to $0$ and solve. As you expected, we get $x=7$: the "most efficient" way is to use a cube.  Now argue this really gives the minimum surface area.

Answer (score 1):

The volume of a box with a squared base is: $V=a^2\cdot h$

The surface is $S=2a^2+4ah$.

So minimize $g(a,h)=2a^2+4ah$ with the condition $a^2\cdot h=343$

Solve $a^2\cdot h=343$ for h and insert the mathematical expression for h in  $2a^2+4ah$.

Then calculate $g'(a)$ and solve the equation $g'(a)=0$

greetings,

calculus

Comment: Am I supposed to get a really odd answer?

Comment: What´s your problem ?